# Render section inside layout file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to understand how works sections in Razor views. I have 2 layout files:  `_Layout.cshtml` and  `_LayoutChild.cshtml` which use the first layout inside. I try to declare sections in `_Layout.cshtml` and render it in the same file. Markup not appears but when I declare section in `_LayoutChild.cshtml` everything works. See example below:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    @RenderSection("A", false)
  </head>
  <body>
    @section A{
      <script>
        alert("I'm in Layout!");
      </script>
    }
  </body>
</html>
```

_LayoutChild.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@section A{
   <script>
        alert("I'm in LayoutChild!");
   </script>
}
```

I understand that declaring section in the same file looks strange but I would like to know why it don't work?

Comment: see I would consider _layoutchild.cshtml as a partial.  therefore so I wouldn't use `@RenderSection()` but `@Html.Partial()`.  I think this will explain abit better.  https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor while old it is still relevant

Comment: Come to think of this it will never work like you expect.  `@RenderBody()` is expected in the _layout.cshtml.  then once you are rendering for example `Index` (the section would be inside the actual `index` vs the layout).

Comment: I think _LayoutChild.cshtml  is used as a view file. right ?

Answer (score 1):

While developing web site or application. Every page have some common section like header, footer, sidebar etc. Write and maintain these on every page is a hard job. So, we need a way to put them in one single place. Luckily in MVC we have Layout concept for this. We put all the common code in it and changing content in `Views` which will render in layout where we call `@RenderBody()` method.

**Why we need `sections` ?**

Some time we wanted to show specific content on some specific pages like newletters only show on blogs and home page, top news or some advertising banners on specific pages. For these type of scenarios `sections` rescue us in MVC.

**How we can use `section` ?**

We need to follow these two steps to used sections in MVC.

1. Declare Section in Layout, give it a name and tell is it required on
   every page or not.
2. Define it in view

When views render then section content also added where we declare the section.

**Code Example**

**1.** Most of the time we need some specific javascript code for view. So we can do it like this

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**view.cshtml**

```
 @section scripts{
      <script>
        alert("I'm in Layout!");
      </script>
    }
```

**2.** News Letter example

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
  @RenderSection("newletter", required: false)
```

**view.cshtml**

```
 @section newletter{
     <h3> New Letter </h3>
     ... rest of the html ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for informative reply but it don't explain the problem I've been faced with.